# How to change file limit on SharePoint Online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, file-upload, limitations

[image]

I would like to know how I can change file limits in a document library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clear cut answer is:

> No, You cannot change the limit of Threshold in SharePoint Online.

Already answer this [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/167100/30145).

You can handle your large list using [Manage large lists and libraries in Office 365](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-Office-365-b4038448-ec0e-49b7-b853-679d3d8fb784?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1).

For your more information you can visit

- [Office 365 : How SharePoint Online handles List View Threshold](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2016/03/29/office-365-how-sharepoint-online-handles-list-view-threshold/)
- [The number of items in this list exceeds the list view threshold](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2759051/the-number-of-items-in-this-list-exceeds-the-list-view-threshold-erro)

What you can do is divide your files in folders in document library.